# MailMessage, display name of sender is "???????"

Tags: c#, smtpclient, mailmessage

The problem: I get "???????" instead of display name of sender (display name is the utf8 text, also tried using System.Web.Mail.MailMessage but got the same result):

```
var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@mail.com", "Some UTF8 text");
    var toAddress = new MailAddress(toAddress);

    var client = new SmtpClient
    {
        Host = "smpt.server",
        Port = 465,
        EnableSsl = true,
        DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
        UseDefaultCredentials = false,
        Credentials = new NetworkCredential(fromAddress.Address, "password"),
        Timeout = 5000
    };
    var message = new MailMessage(fromAddress, toAddress)
    {
        Subject = title,
        Body = messageStr,
        IsBodyHtml = true
    };
```

Comment: Where are you getting the display name from? Since you know it is UTF8, you could attempt to convert it to unicode.

Comment: Does your SMTP server support Unicode? The MailAddress class does, according to the documentation.

Comment: I noticed strange thing: when I use CDO.Message, before sending email I have tried to check sender address using QuickWatch and saw "\"???? ?????????\" <office@portal.ua>"

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried changing the constructor?

```
 var fromAddress = new MailAddress("from@mail.com", "Some UTF8 text", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8);
```

[MailAddress Constructor (String, String, Encoding)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f52hswkf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: From that same page: _"UTF8 is the default encoding if none is specified"_.